# Is there a way to calculate thrust without running experiments?

Tags: turbojet

Is there any way to calculate the thrust generated without conducting experiments? In my case I need to figure out thrust generated by electric duct fans and/or turbojets.

Comment: A real world set up or some theoretical motor?

Comment: Yes, but you have to know more than is indicated in your question.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of an electric motor driving a propeller, you can get a rough approximation for the thrust t from the power p consumed by the motor when the plane is flying with a constant velocity v, since $p = t \times v$. Of course, you should use coherent units, as newtons, m/s and watts, and include a large correction factor, as the real efficiency will be very far from 100%...

For the stationary case, in [Wikipedia (entry 'disk loading')](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_loading#Momentum_theory) you can find an expression for the stationary case, derived from momentum considerations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the performance of a gas turbine engine, you can use a program like [GasTurb](http://www.gasturb.de). It will handle any gas turbine configuration, but it may not be able to calculate the thrust for your electric duct fan.